# ActionBar adding spinner not connected to tab content paging

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock along with a ViewPager for tab content switching (swipe) using fragments.

http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/1040/device20120717232738.png

What I would need, is to have two spinner controls in ActionBar that are not connected to tabs switching. So different controls(so two spinners), have their own onClick logic. On my image the two action buttons(EUR and KUPOVNI) should be spinners.

Is the proper way of doing this using custom views for ActionBar?

Comment: Post your code and you will have more success.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, in the meantime, I removed that options from Action Bar down to regular content as normal Spinner controls. For me, it is still a better (at least more UI friendly design) to be in Action Bar, so I will try to fetch that piece of code and bring it on this page.